# Converting crystal reports to PDF or Microsoft Excel

Tags: asp.net, excel, crystal-reports

I have a crystal report on my ASP.NET website and it is successfully displayed but it fails to be exported to Microsoft Access. The client's operating system is Windows 8 32 bits. Here is the error that shows up:[image]

I'd highly appreicate any suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you been able to solve this problem with the suggestion given below?

Answer (score 0):

first you need to add radio buttons as follow:

```
      <tr>
          <td>
          </td>
          <td>
          <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblFormat" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" CssClass="Profiletitletxt">
          <asp:ListItem Text="PDF" Value="1" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
          <asp:ListItem Text="MS Word" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
          <asp:ListItem Text="MS Excel" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
          </asp:RadioButtonList>

          </td>
          <td>
          </td>
          </tr>
```

in your code at bind report add :

```
           If rblFormat.SelectedValue = 1 Then
                cryRpt.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, Response, True, "ExportedReport")
            ElseIf rblFormat.SelectedValue = 2 Then
                cryRpt.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType.WordForWindows, Response, True, "ExportedReport")
            ElseIf rblFormat.SelectedValue = 3 Then
            ExportDataSetToExcel(DT, "ExportedReport")
            End If
```

For Excel add:

```
        Public Shared Sub ExportDataSetToExcel(ByVal ds As DataTable, ByVal filename As String)
        Dim response As HttpResponse = HttpContext.Current.Response
        response.Clear()
        response.Buffer = True
        response.Charset = ""
        response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
            Using sw As New StringWriter()
            Using htw As New HtmlTextWriter(sw)
                Dim dg As New DataGrid()
                dg.DataSource = ds
                dg.DataBind()
                dg.RenderControl(htw)
                response.Charset = "UTF-8"
                response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
                response.BinaryWrite(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetPreamble())
                response.Output.Write(sw.ToString())
                response.[End]()
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub
```